# How to use a for loop index outside of for loop in C (selection sort)

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop, nested, selection-sort

I am trying to do a selection sort where I am going through a list of integers, picking out the smallest number, and swapping it with a bigger number earlier in the list. This code is just practicing with a short string of 4 integers. What I am struggling with is getting through the whole list of integers to find the smallest number before moving on. I found that this works great as its own nested for loop, but then I can't 'remember' at which index that smallest number was at when trying to swap integers (this would be the line of code that is commented out, as it will not know what 'j' is). If I attempt doing this within the for loop then I prematurely swap the first integer that is smaller than the one I am swapping with before seeing if there are any other smaller integers. Any tips in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
int main (void)
{

    int tmp;
    int n = 4;
    int values[] = {5,3,4,1};



    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {    
        int minimum = values[i];

        for (int j=1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (values[j]<minimum)
            {   
                minimum=values[j];
            }

        }

        tmp = values[i];
        values[i] = minimum;
        //values[j] = tmp;    

    }
}
```

Comment: You can remember `j` in another variable such as `minimum_j = j` where `int minimum_j` is defined at function scope. Or `i` or whatever.

Comment: `int minimum = values[i];` --> `int min_i = i;` like [this](http://ideone.com/jXJvs4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a variable `minimumIndex` which is the index of the minimum value. Set it to `j` when you update the value of `minimum`, and it will give you the index of the minimum at the end of the loop. Make also to initialize it with a correct value: Since `mimimum` is initialized to `values[i]`, `minimumIndex` should be initialized to `i`.

Note also that you have a bug: You start the inner loop at `j=1`, but it should start with `i` or `i+1` so that you skip over the elements which have already been placed.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes sense.

Comment: Could I ask you to clarify how/why to initialize minimumIndex to i? when I first declare the variable I set it equal to i? if I don't do this won't the initialized value just be overwritten by the updated index when the minimum value is set?

Comment: @Josh You initialize `minimum` to `values[i]`. If that's actually the minimum value, then the `if` condition will never be true so you want `minimumIndex` to be `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the index of the element with the minimal value. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{
    int values[] = { 5, 3, 4, 1 };
    size_t n = sizeof( values ) / sizeof( *values );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", values[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {    
        size_t minimum = i;

        for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
        {
            if ( values[j] < values[minimum] )
            {   
                minimum = j;
            }
        }

        if ( minimum != i )
        {
            int tmp = values[i];
            values[i] = values[minimum];
            values[minimum] = tmp;    
        }
    } 

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d ", values[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

Pay attention to that the index of the inner loop should start with the value `i + 1`.

```
for ( size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++ )
                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to go through this, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Could I ask you why you create the data type size_t? I have not seen this before, would it suffice just to use an int data type?

Comment: @Josh size_t is an integer type usually defined as an alias for the type unsigned long. This type is used by the operator sizeof and the string functions declared in the header <string.h> as for example the function strlen. The problem is that arrays can be so big that the type int can be unable to store all indices of such an array.